# Ember.js: Using an ArrayController without a route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of categories that I would like to display on the page.  I've been looking around for hours on the correct way to do this, but I keep finding conflicting information and methods that are either no longer working with the current version of Ember, or are deprecated.

To create the app and Ember-Data thing:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

I am using Ember-Data with some fixture data for the categories:

```
App.Category.FIXTURES = [{
  id:          1,
  name:        'Category 1',
  description: 'The first category'
}, {
  id:          2,
  name:        'Category 2',
  description: 'The second category'
}];
```

I then create a model to represent an instance of a category (the "versions" relates to a different model where version instances have category instances):

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  versions:    DS.hasMany('version'),
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Then I made an ArrayController, but I am having trouble populating the content.

```
App.CatagoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  init: function () {
    this.set('content', ???);
  }
});
```

This isn't hooked up to a route since it isn't navigable, so I can't use the "model" property in a route.

Replacing the `???` in the ArrayController, I've tried several things:

I tried `this.store.find('category')` like the examples show for routes, but I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null".

I tried `App.Store.find('category')` and that gave me the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Any help or a push in the right direction is appreciated.  I have a feeling I'm not even headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

First, remember that controllers are singletons. So your `init` function will only fire once for the entire lifecycle of your application (which probably isn't what you want). But that doesn't really matter, since...

The way that you're handling models isn't the way that Ember.js is set up for. You shouldn't be fetching models in controllers, only routes. That's why there is no `store` property on the controller. You need to implement the `model` hook on your route, like this:

```
App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('category');
    }
});
```

From there, Ember will automatically set the `model` property (*not* the `content` property, don't use that) on your controller to the data that you return from the `model` hook.

So, just eliminate the `content` property and `init` function from your controller, and implement that hook in your model, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So it is okay to have a route for something even if it should not be navigable via the URL?  From all the examples I've seen, I was under the impressions that Ember Routes were always directly linked to URLs.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask about that in my answer. When you say it isn't navigable, how do you get to the page that displays this data?

Comment: I guess the point is that every page should have a location (URL). Even if that location may be embedded in another page. There are ways to have controllers without routes, but they still require a location of some sort.

Comment: I have objects called "Versions", each of which belong to a category.  So I have a route "/version/:version_id" which shows a UI with information for that version, but I'd like to allow the user to change the category.  So I need to get the list of categories to put them into a selection list.  Since there could be multiple places in my application that needs this category list, I am assuming there is a good way to write it in Ember to avoid code re-use (so, not having the code to fetch the categories inside the Version controller).

Comment: You'll probably want to start by using the [application template](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/). As you work with Ember.js more, you'll see more and more ways you can nest your templates (and routes) to eliminate code duplication.

Comment: I have a template and everything set up for the Versions page--that all works fine.  The problem is that I need to fetch the list of categories to stick into the versions page, since I can't hard-code them (they can change often).

Comment: You wouldn't hardcode them, you use your `ApplicationRoute` and `ApplicationController` to insert them into the page as you would any other model.

Comment: So there isn't a way to just have an ArrayController without a route?  It seems like it would just lead to messy code if I had to stick everything like this into the ApplicationRoute/Controller... why wouldn't EmberJS support this type of standard componentization?

Comment: I don't understand, what would a controller without a route do? Where would it's properties be used? How would it's actions be called?

Comment: I don't know, I can't find any helpful examples anywhere. Every example for Ember is the exact same thing with a different noun, and none of them cover anything beyond absolute basics. In my situation, I have a "Versions" page backed by a Version Route/Model/Controller/View. On this page, I want to have a list of categories. Since the categories change, I want to have them loaded from the database like everything else, so I made a Category model. From there, I don't understand how to get that list of categories onto the page without duplicating a bunch of code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51133/discussion-between-gjk-and-mike)